# Metric values at method level

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am exporting the Java data from Sonar via the Web Service /api/resources as described in http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2752802.

Can I obtain the metrics at the method level?

For example, the complexity is also available as "function_complexity", but this is the average per class of the complexity of all methods. This average is rather meaningless as typically the few high values of the really complex methods are combined with the many low values of all getters and setters. Therefore, I want to obtain the complexity of each method, or at least all methods with a complexity that exceeds a certain limit.

I had expected some qualifier related to methods, like "MTH", but I cannot find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, metrics are not stored at that level.